# Yii2 twig HTML helper functions not working

Tags: twig, yii2

**Problem**

I'm using yii2 with the twig templating engine. It seems to be working however I can't seem to use any of the methods of the Html helpers (yii/helpers/Html).

My view is extending a base layout using twig extends. `{% extends "@layouts/_base.twig" %}`

I am including 'yii/helpers/Html' in the _base.twig file. `{{ use('yii/helpers/Html') }}`

I'm using `{{ html.encode(this.title) }}` to render the page title in the header and

```
{{ html.submitButton('Send Message', {
   'class': 'button button--cta button--expand',
}) | raw }}
```

to try and render a button in my view but neither seems to work, I don't get any errors, just nothing rendering.

**Question**

Have I set this up correctly? What should I have to do to render a button in yii2 twig? Very new to using twig.

**Code**

**index.twig**

```
{% extends "@layouts/_base.twig" %}

{% block layout %}

...

  {% set form = active_form_begin({
    'id' : 'contact-us-form'
  }) %}

...

  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-8 medium-offset-2 columns">

      {{ form.field(contact_us, 'full_name').textArea([{
        'rows' : 6,
        'placeholder' : 'Let us know if you have any questions...'
      }]).label('Message', {
        'class' : 'label--inline'
      }) | raw }}

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-3 medium-offset-2 columns">

        {{ html.submitButton('Send Message', {
          'class': 'button button--cta button--expand',
        }) | raw }}

      </div>
    </div>

    {{ active_form_end() }}
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

**_base.twig**

```
{{ use('yii/helpers/Html') }}
{{ use('yii/widgets/ActiveForm') }}
{{ use('yii/web/JqueryAsset') }}

{{ this.beginPage() }}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{app.language}}">

    <head>
        {{ this.head() }}
        <meta charset="{{app.charset}}">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        {{ html.csrfMetaTags() | raw }}
        {{ register_asset_bundle('www/assets/AppAsset') }}
        <title>{{ html.encode(this.title) }}</title>

    </head>

    <body>
    {{ this.beginBody() }}

    {% block header %}
        {% include "@layouts/components/header.twig" %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block layout %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
        {% include "@layouts/components/footer.twig" %}
    {% endblock %}

    {{ this.endBody() }}
    </body>
</html>
{{ this.endPage() }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use \yii/helpers\Html helper in twig templates you need to configure twig extension accordingly. This is covered in [documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig/blob/master/docs/guide/additional-configuration.md#globals), Additional Configuration page.

You need to add 'globals' option inside 'twig' section of configuration (see 'THIS LINE' mark):

**For yiisoft/yii2-twig version 2.1.0:**

```php
[
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
 /* *THIS LINE* */  'globals' => ['html' => ['class'=>'\yii\helpers\Html']],
                    'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
                ],
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Then just use it in template as 'html' variable, example:

```
{{ html.csrfMetaTags() | raw }}
```

**For yiisoft/yii2-twig version 2.0.6 and earlier** there was old syntax:

```
'globals' => ['html' => '\yii\helpers\Html'], // *THIS LINE*
```

Comment: For some reason, this is not working anymore. @hesselek's answer does work.

Comment: @clapas thanks, looks like syntax has been changed in v2.1.0 of yii2-twig extension. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According actual [documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig/blob/master/docs/guide/additional-configuration.md#globals), the correct form must be:

```
    [
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
                    'globals' => ['html' => ['class'=>'\yii\helpers\Html']], // *THIS LINE*
                    'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
                ],
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

I don't know why, the former "html"=>'\yii\helpers\html' not works in one of my recents projects.